# Error "Move-SPSite : Execution Timeout Expired."

Tags: site-collection, content-database, move

I want to move a 30GB Site Collection to another content database. This should be done with PowerShell with the Move-SPSite command. After about 40 Minutes the job stops with the following error Message:

> Move-SPSite : Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>   At line:27 char:1
>   + Move-SPSite -Identity $SiteUrl -DestinationDatabase $DestinationDB -Confirm:$fal ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...PCmdletMoveSite:SPCmdletMoveSite) [Move-SPSite], SPCmdletException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletMoveSite

We've increased the execution timeout but this helped nothing. We tried the command also with other site collections and everything worked fine. Any ideas what we can do?

Comment: if it is a complex structure site then that can happen...how many sites in the database and their sizes??

Comment: There's only one site in the database with about 30GB of data. In the site there are some Document Libraries and also task lists with single item permissions. the logic will be done with a javascript framework. We've also talked to the developers but they even don't know what is wrong.

Comment: what is the reason to move to different DB? if it is only one site in the db.

Comment: We get sql blockings only with this content database (something with acl and the perms table) and we want to be shure that the db is not corrupt. So it would be a try to move the site collection to another db.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen before, I ended up using backup-spsite and restore-spsite commands instead.  It is not fast but you can accomplish the same end result.

Comment: we've tried the backup and restore with PowerShell but it is also not working ...